# How can I programmatically interact with a video game GUI

Tags: user-interface, ocr

Before I get shot down on this one, I realize that the 'how' answer for this question might be slightly debatable, however I'm more interested in the 'what'.

In a nut shell I want to know which methods I can use to interact with a PC video game interface. I want to create a program that can extract data from a video game market interface.

My first initial thought was that I would need to programmatically take screen shots and then use some Optical Character Recognition software to extract the text. Then run whatever operation on the extracted text to derive my incites.

Then I was thinking it might just be easier to have a bunch of mini screen shots that I just use to find matches on certain sections of the screen. When a match is found, I would then know what the text is on the screen, without having to actually 'extract' it.

For those out there whom have done this, can you point me in one direction or the other? Perhaps there is a method that I am completely unaware of.

If its the case that this question is not suitable for this forum. It would be much appreciated if you could direct me elsewhere.

Edit: I should probably add that I'm not looking to spend a fortune on this project... so any free software would be the best. Perhaps that's a tall order.

Comment: Quick test pro is one product on the market that might help

Comment: So is Ranorex is another

Comment: I'll check those out, thanks Ed

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting to think Sikuli is the direction I'm going to go. Open Source image recognition software, integrates with Python, Ruby, Java, JDBC, JavaScript and more.

-- Expanding on the question --

There are basically 3 categories of tools:

**Recorder** while you manually work along your workflow, a recorder tracks your mouse and keyboard actions. After stopping the recording, you might playback (autorun your worflow). The recordings can usually be edited and augmented with additional features.

**GUI aware** the tool allows to programmatically operate on GUI elements like buttons. This is based on the knowledge of internal structures and names of the GUI elements and their features. Some of these tools also have a recording feature.

**Visually** the tool “sees” images (usually retangular pixel areas) on the screen and allows to act on these images using mouse and keyboard simulation. There might be some recorder feture as well with such a tool.

SikuliX belongs to the 3rd category and currently does not have a recorder feature.

Answer in progress...

Answer (score 0):

In games with moddable UIs, like many MMOs, you could create a mod that streams data through a series of black and white squares that could be read with optical sensors.  From there, a microcontroller could deliver the data back to the PC via USB or wifi.

Answer (score 0):

My approach as a noob. First determine if OCR 100% needed, I think this plays a role in speed.

if possible:
-run game in window (allows for trouble shooting and easy troubleshooting)
-is there a high contrast option for game? Will help Sikuli find things

then you plan out your scenarios:
You have to create different functions for different situations. A lot of gaming is "do you see this?" Then "do this" until that is gone.

Start with small parts you want to automate then build on them. Making sure your parts can scale in case small change need to happen, they will. For instance you want to open the menu if you see an object, lets say a tree.
Assume you have some sort of walking algorithm.

```
setROI(region1) #focus here for tree
if exists(tRee):
    click(loCation) #you could hit the shortcut key to opening the menu
    click(iTem) #if the item moves in the menu then you may need to scroll to find it first or you can change the ROI and start seeing if sikuli can differentiate your item from one you dont want to click.
```

You would get that to loop into other actions and proceed. Goodluck.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the high contrast setting! I'll make sure to play with that setting.